# Empirical Quantile Comparison Effect Size

Tags: python, scipy, quantile, ecdf

I'm trying to recreate the following integral with empirical data:

[image]

where F, G are cdfs and their inverses are quantile functions.

Here's my code:

```
def eqces(u,v):
    import numpy as np
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    from scipy.stats.mstats import mquantiles

    ecdfu = sm.distributions.ECDF(u)
    ecdfv = sm.distributions.ECDF(v)
    p = np.concatenate([ecdfu.y, ecdfv.y])
    p = np.unique(p) 
    p.sort()

    qfu = mquantiles(u, p)
    qfv = mquantiles(v, p)

    uvinv = ecdfu(qfv)
    vuinv = ecdfv(qfu)

    result = abs(uvinv - p) + abs(vuinv - p)
    return np.dot(result, np.ones(p.size))
```

With this I would expect that `eqces(u,u) = 0` for `u = np.random.uniform(0,1,50)` but this is generally not the case. Can anyone tell if i'm doing something wrong or suggest alternatives?

`Edit`

This code seems to work better with some analytical results:

```
def eqces(u,v): 
    ecdfu = sm.distributions.ECDF(u)
    ecdfv = sm.distributions.ECDF(v)

    p = np.concatenate([ecdfu.y, ecdfv.y])
    X = np.concatenate([ecdfu.x, ecdfv.x])

    return 2*np.dot(np.abs(ecdfu(X)-p)+np.abs(ecdfv(X)-p), np.ones(p.size))/p.size
```

Comment: can you please fix your formatting?

Comment: @tcaswell I'm not quite sure how to add the latex format on this question. Could you direct me to some guidelines on that? I tried looking around but couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: SO won't do tex markup (that I am aware of).  I was more concerned with the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `ECDF` and `mquantiles` don't use the same *plotting positions*

`mquantiles` has the optional keywords `alphap=0.4, betap=0.4`.

`p` and `uvinv` will not round-trip in this case.

However, in large sample the difference should be small.

`scipy.stats.ks_2samp` is doing something similar, but working directly with numpy without helper functions.

BTW: Does this distance measure between the two distributions have a name?

Comment: I found it referenced as "Quantile Comparison Effect Size," a metric for the difference between two non normal, non parametric (arbitrary) distributions.